# Creating an array method that "shifts" a character into a different character. IE: a into b

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to create a program that encrypts a string from user input then saves it into a 2-dimensional array. For instance, if I typed in the word "Car", C is at [0][0], a is at [1][0], and r is [2][0]. Then I would input a number of 1-4 and "shift" the letters down that many times and stores it in index [][1]. So if I chose 3, Car would change into Fdu and it would be stored inside index [0][1],[1][1], and [2][1].

For the actual encryption, I have to create a separate method called caesarCipher to do all the calculations and assignments based on the number supplied by the user. My problem is being a very new coder, is that I can't figure out exactly how to create the method to accomplish this. I believe a switch statement would be easiest to handle each case of 1, 2,3, or 4 but not certain as to what I can use to actually change the characters.

```
String userInput;
int encryption;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a message you would like to encrypt.");
userInput = scan.nextLine();

int arrayLength = userInput.length();

//creates the array for outputting the message before and after encryption
char[][] outputArray = new char [arrayLength][3];

//for loop that supplies the message into the array, a different index per character
for (int index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++)
{
  outputArray[index][0] = userInput.charAt(index);
  System.out.print(outputArray[index]);
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 4. This will decide how to encrypt your message");
encryption = scan.nextInt();

//switch statement that changes the message based on the selected number
switch(encryption)
{
  case 1:
    if (encryption == 1)
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++)
      outputArray[index][1] = userInput.charAt(index);
    break;
  case 2:
    if (encryption == 2)
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++)
      outputArray[index][1] = userInput.charAt(index);
    break;  
  case 3:
    if (encryption == 3)
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++)
      outputArray[index][1] = userInput.charAt(index);
    break;
  case 4:
    if (encryption == 4)
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++)
      outputArray[index][1] = userInput.charAt(index);
    break;
}
```

This is what I have so far with the switch statement set-up for each case, but obviously, nothing that changes the characters.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Since you're using ASCII values, it can be accomplished using `int` to `char` and `char` to `int` casting in Java.

Create an array to store the characters,

```java
char outputArray[][] = new char[userInput.length()][2];
```

Store the user input into the array as you have. Then, add the `encryption` value to ASCII value of the original character. Finally, cast the sum as a `char` before storing it in your array.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
  int newAscii = outputArray[i][0] + encryption;
  outputArray[i][1] = (char) newAscii;
}
```

For the constraint of `encryption` being between 1 to 4, you can add a simple if...else statement after getting the user input. There's no need to use switch-case this way. But if you do, you can skip with `if (encryption == 1)` once you're already inside `case 1`.

Comment: Following your advice for the code, returns an "error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to java.lang.String" and changing both Strings to char allows it to compile, but for it returns [[C@7376d262

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the code should allow and also modify numbers, capital letters, and punctuation. And if a "z" is used, it should change into what follows it according to an ASCII table, so 1 is {, 2 is |, 3 is }, and 4 is `

Comment: Check the edit to my answer, you can use type casting in such a case. Also, you may want to update your original question to include these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a 2D array or a string of alphabetic characters.  You can use a little math to help you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    String word = encrypt("Car", i);
    System.out
            .println("Car -> " + word + " for shift = " + i);
}
```

Prints

```
Car -> Car for shift = 0
Car -> Dbs for shift = 1
Car -> Ect for shift = 2
Car -> Fdu for shift = 3
Car -> Gev for shift = 4
Car -> Hfw for shift = 5
Car -> Igx for shift = 6
Car -> Jhy for shift = 7
Car -> Kiz for shift = 8
Car -> Lja for shift = 9
Car -> Mkb for shift = 10
Car -> Nlc for shift = 11
Car -> Omd for shift = 12
Car -> Pne for shift = 13
Car -> Qof for shift = 14
Car -> Rpg for shift = 15
Car -> Sqh for shift = 16
Car -> Tri for shift = 17
Car -> Usj for shift = 18
Car -> Vtk for shift = 19
Car -> Wul for shift = 20
Car -> Xvm for shift = 21
Car -> Ywn for shift = 22
Car -> Zxo for shift = 23
Car -> Ayp for shift = 24
Car -> Bzq for shift = 25
```

The following works like this.

- take a character `r` for instance.
- subtract `a` (the first character in the alphabet.  `a`-`a` would be `0`, `b`-`a` would be `1` and so on.
- so `r`-`a` is 18.  Then add your cypher, say it is a `12`.  So the sum is `18+12 = 30`.
- but there are only `26` letters so you need to wrap around.  Using the remainder operator (`%`) `30 % 26 is 4`.  Now add `a` back to get the character which would be `d`.
- repeat for all characters.
- you can preserve case by checking the original character's case and modify the encrypted one accordingly.
- The returned string is built by appending the characters to an instance of `StringBuilder`

```
public static String encrypt(String word, int shift) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        char ch = (char)((Character.toLowerCase(c)-'a' + shift)%26+'a');
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
        }
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();   
}
```

Note that the above presumes you are using a character set that lends itself to such a positional manipulation (e.g. ASCII).

Comment: The output ultimately has to be in a 2D array based on the rules of the assignment. As for the code itself, I'm not sure which would be easier to use, the ASCII table, or Unicode table. I believe Unicode would be easier as I have to allow, and also modify punctuation and numbers. And if the user uses z, it should change into the 4 characters that follow it e.g. 1 is {, 2 is |, 3 is }, and 4 is `

Comment: Based on what you just described, some characters will not be printable.  You should modify your question to include these detailed requirements,.